# SwiftUI Generic ContextMenu view

Tags: generics, swiftui, contextmenu

I have a list showing product images and some basic info.

When user clicks on a particular product image, it would actually show a context menu for actions like "save image" etc.

The following is a simplified sample code for what I have.

```
    Image("imageofProduct1")
        .contextMenu {
            Button("Save", action: {
                // Proceed with save function for Product 1
            })
    }
```

Since I may have product images in different parts of the application.  Is there a way for me to create a generic ContextMenu where it will display the same "save" action, but also able to accept the name of the image of interest.

Currently, I am able to move the context menu into the following :

```
func ContextMenuContent() -> some View {
    return Button("Save") {
        // Save function of the image
    }
}
```

In the main body, I am able to display the same context menu :

```
Image("imageofProduct1")
        .contextMenu(menuItems: ContextMenuContent)
```

If I am to move the ContextMenu function into a separate file.  For encapsulation, is it possible for me to somehow pass in the name of the image, so that the image saving function will be executed based on the name of the image supplied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach can be as follows

```
func ContextMenuContent(_ imageName: String) -> some View {
    return Button("Save") {
        // Save function of the image
        // use imageName here
    }
}
```

and usage

**Updated:** (tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
// it does not matter how it get here
let imageName = "imageofProduct1" 

//...

Image(imageName) // or same constant here and below
        .contextMenu { ContextMenuContent(imageName) } // here !!
```

Comment: The solution worked like a charm with some syntax updates to my original code.  Thsnk you very much for your hrlp!